# woocommerce csv upload takes too much time

Tags: wordpress, upload, woocommerce, product

I have a site and I have a problem regarding this is that I have to upload 25K products and it take 2-3 days to upload to woo commerce. The other thing is that if I have to update the price for products like 2-300 then I have to update the csv and then delete all the products and then re-uploading all products.
Any better solution?